# Nginx reverse proxy for keycloak

Tags: docker, nginx, keycloak, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've deployed a keycloak server at localhost:7070 (in Docker container, it run on 8080), now I want to setup a reverse proxy for it. Here is my conf:

```
server {
    listen       11080 ;

    location /auth/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass  http://localhost:7070/auth/;
    }
}
```

when I access `http://my-ip:11080/auth`, I could see the welcome page. But when I tried to login following the link on the welcome page, then it show error and the url now is `http://my-ip:auth/admin/`, but I expect `http://my-ip:11080/auth/admin/` with the port **11080**

When I manually type `http://my-ip:11080/auth/admin` and press Enter, it redirect to `http://my-ip/auth/admin/master/console/`, but I expect `http://my-ip:11080/auth/admin/master/console/`  with the port **11080**

I also tried many solutions that I found but no luck for now. Could you guy tell me what is the problem here?

**UPDATE:** docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  keycloak:
    volumes:
      - keycloak-pgdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "7070:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_VENDOR=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
      - DB_ADDR=localhost
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=root
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
volumes:
  keycloak-pgdb:
```

Docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                   COMMAND           CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                               NAMES
30ad65460a0c  pic-keycloak_keycloak   "entrypoint.sh"   38 minutes ago   Up 38 minutes   5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7070->8080/tcp    pic-keycloak_keycloak_1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application in the container is not aware that you are forwarding port `11080`, so when the application renders the response, if it's following the `X-Forwarded-xxxxx` headers, it will use the `X-Forwarded-Poroto` to determine where the redirection should be sent.

Depending on your application, you have 2 options do deal with this cases:

1. Application that recognizes a `X-Forwarded-Port` header can be told to redirect to a specific port, like in this case:

   ```
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 11080
   ```
2. Legacy application that do not obey the rules provided in the header can be handled by response rewrite pass. Here is example with [sub_filter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html):

   ```
   sub_filter     'http:/my-ip/auth'    'http:/my-ip:11080/auth';
   ```

   For sub_filter to work, the module should be installed and enabled `--with-http_sub_module`

Comment: Hi jordanvrtanoski, thanks for your suggestion. Should I use the 1st solution or the 2nd solution for best practice?

Comment: The 1st is the best practice, but some older framework had not implemented the header. If the 1st is not working, than the 2nd is a way to handling trough `nginX`